# APP_PROTECT failed to get compilation status

Tags: nginx, compilation

I have installed Nginx Plus and App Protect (provided by Nginx Plus and F5). I followed the config guide (https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-app-protect/configuration/). The issue is whenever I add the lines

```
app_protect_enable on;
/etc/app_protect/conf/NginxDefaultPolicy.json";
```

In nginx.conf (as shown in the config guide link above), I am getting a weird error which says APP_PROTECT failed to get compilation status.

Nginx error log shows this:

```
2021/11/01 02:37:16 [notice] 5967#5967: APP_PROTECT { "event": "configuration_load_start", "configSetFile": "/opt/app_protect/config/config_set.json" }
2021/11/01 02:37:16 [error] 5967#5967: APP_PROTECT failed to get compilation status
```

Please help if anyone else is facing the same problem. Emailed to nginx plus support and I am yet to receive a reply from them (48 hours have passed since emailing them)

Comment: could it be, that app_protect_policy_file is missing? a Standalone File can never be a valid argument in nginx - NEVER :-)

Comment: I followed the guide to set up app protect. It was the default file so I don't see any issues.